# sorting table on elements that don't belong to the table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have table with information about links. But I can sort in only by the created date and name. How can I sort on item that belongs to links?

```
def links_all
          per_page = 60
          Links.limit(per_page).offset( (@page - 1) * per_page ).order(@sort_column + " " +  @sort_direction).map do |s|
            {  
              :name => s.name,
              :item_num => s.items.count,
              :comments_num => s.comments.count,
              :user_name => s.user ? s.user.name : "" ,
              :created_at => s.created_at.to_formatted_s(:db) ,
              :user_id => s.user ? s.user.id : "" ,
              :streme_id => s.id,
              :streme_views =>  s.views ? s.views : "" 
            }
          end
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort by an association's column you need to `join` it. For example, to sort `links` by  `user.name`:

```
Links.joins(:user).order("users.name")
```